# Passing different Extras to different setDisplayIntent, but same is received

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, wear-os

I am in a case where my Watch application has updated data and will display these data in multiple pages.

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133449/327402 , I created a displayIntent for each one of my page.

```
List extras = new ArrayList();

//This is a loop to create every individual Notification
for (Route aRoute : myRoutes) {
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    String toSend = aRoute.detail;
    Log.d("CVE",toSend);
    viewIntent.putExtra("KEY", toSend);

    PendingIntent displayendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,viewIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification aNotif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
        .setDisplayIntent(displayendingIntent)
        .setCustomSizePreset(Notification.WearableExtender.SIZE_MEDIUM))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .build();

    extras.add(aNotif);
}

//This is "main" notification.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(desc)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

Notification notification = builder1
                        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
.addPages(extras))
.build();

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Till here, it looks OK, but when I read what happens on every notification, I realize that the data is the same.

This is my simplified Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    mTextView.setText("Value: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY"));
}
```

The problem is that the Log (see line 6 of the first part part of the code) displays correctly:

"Text 1"
"Text 2"
"Text 3"

, but in reality, "Text 3" is displayed in every Notification!

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use 0 as request code for your PendingIntent, but a different unique value for each object your request. E.g.

```
int counter = 0;
for (Route aRoute : myRoutes) {
    // other code
    PendingIntent displayendingIntent  
         = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), counter++, 
                             viewIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   // other code
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I now feel stupid to have asked this question :-p

Comment: you shouldn't. The documentation is not clear about that